# R: How to classify strings based on a set of regular expressions

Tags: r, regex, string, stringr

I have a vector of text strings that describe the sources for images in a book, but not in an entirely consistent format--- they are captured from the LaTeX source & written to a text file.

I need to process these and collect information about the source attribution
and permission status.  A sample of strings looks like this:

```
strings <- '
GBD 2016 Alcohol Collaborators (2018)
\citet {DeBoldFriedman:2015}, permission required
Author graphic, using various public domain images
\url {http://www.histogames.com/HTML/inventaire/periodes-historiques/prehistoire.php}
\url {https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Egyptmotionseries.jpg}
\url {http://commons.wikimedia.org}, public domain.
\citet {Plot:1685}, author image collection
Author image collection
 From \citet {Priestley:1765}, author image collection
 Author image collection
 Courtesy Library of Congress
\citet {Langren:1644}, image courtesy of the Koninklijke Bibliotheek van Belgi\"e 
Public domain
Author graphic
Author graphic
Author graphic
Author image collection
Wikipedia, https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Tablas\_alfonsies.jpg, public domain
'
```

One main task is to create a variable `status` indicating permission status by finding 
matches to simple regular expressions in the strings.  The categories can be defined by
the following patterns, all of which should be matched to the text of the strings
w/o regard to case.

```
AUpat <- "author (image|graphic|collection)"
PDpat <- "public domain"
REQpat <- "permission required"
LIBpat <- "courtesy|by permission"

# or as a list:
pats <- list(
  'AU' = "author (image|graphic|collection)",
  'PD' = "public domain",
  'REQ'= "permission required",
  'LIB'= "courtesy|by permission"
)
```

Pseudo code to do what I want (doesn't work):

```
status <- rep("", length(strings))
for(i in seq_along(strings)) {
  if      (grep(AUpat, strings[i],  ignore.case=TRUE)) status[i] <- "AU"
  else if (grep(PDpat, strings[i],  ignore.case=TRUE)) status[i] <- "PD"
  else if (grep(REQpat, strings[i], ignore.case=TRUE)) status[i] <- "REQ"
  else if (grep(LIBpat, strings[i], ignore.case=TRUE)) status[i] <- "LIB"
}
```

This is ugly, aside from the fact that it generates an error:

```
Error in if (grep(AUpat, strings[i])) status[i] <- "AU" else if (grep(PDpat,  : 
  argument is of length zero
```

Is there some better way to try to do this task, maybe with `stringr` or other `tidyverse` tools?

Comment: `grep` returns zero or more integers indicating the indices of matches. When nothing is found, it returns `integer(0)`, which is length 0. One patch is to use `if (grepl(AUpat, strings[i], ...))` instead. Having said that, you can vectorize this a bit for better performance ...

Comment: Can you provide another different `strings` entry? This one includes all four of your categories. Can one entry not have more than one classification? Your `pats` seem like orthogonal (unrelated) classifications.

Comment: @r2evans Yes, a string can have more categories, so your answer below gives me a way to deal with that. I normally accept an answer after I have had a chance to test it out, or see what is lacking.  Already up-voted your answer which considered several possibilities. Thx!

Comment: Sorry ... that comment was based on your profile page that shows your 10 most recent questions, many with unaccepted answers. Obviously (since I've answered one or your questions previous to that ... and you accepted that one, thx!) you have a longer history than that. The comment was more based on "encourage newer users to *accept*" than "*hurry, hurry, hurry, accept my answer*". I typically do the same: absorb, test, play, then accept a bit later. Again sorry, premature prod, not meant to pressure for this question. (I'll revisit how I "prod" newer users based on this.)

Comment: OK: I will look at my profile page, and see what I can/should accept. Meanwhile, your Answer gave me all I needed, so I will accepts that, and thank you again for your contribution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks from your patterns as if strings can actually belong to zero or more, not just one. If that's true, then a first step would be to determine which categories (0 or more) a string possesses.

I don't have enough of your `strings` to really test, so I'll generate some simple data and patterns:

```r
strings <- c("something", "something else", "nothing", "nothing here either",
             "something or nothing", "interesting",
             "something interesting", "nothing interesting")

pats <- c(p1 = "something", p2 = "nothing", p3 = "interesting")
```

(The patterns are named as a convenience when the patterns themselves get cumbersome as labels.) Start with generating a `logical` matrix:

```r
m <- sapply(pats, grepl, strings, ignore.case = TRUE)
m
#         p1    p2    p3
# [1,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
# [2,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
# [3,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE
# [4,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE
# [5,]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
# [6,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
# [7,]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
# [8,] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

If you must apply just one category to a string, then assuming the patterns are in order of priority, you can do:

```r
apply(m, 1, function(a) head(c(which(a), NA), n = 1))
# [1] 1 1 2 2 1 3 1 2

names(pats)[ apply(m, 1, function(a) head(c(which(a), 0), n = 1)) ]
# [1] "p1" "p1" "p2" "p2" "p1" "p3" "p1" "p2"
```

Note: this will create `NA`s when strings contain none of the patterns, demonstrating:

```r
m[8,] <- FALSE
apply(m, 1, function(a) head(c(which(a), NA), n = 1))
# [1]  1  1  2  2  1  3  1 NA
```

You should guard against this in your assumptions. (I'll keep `m` with this change for now.)

If you need to preserve the categories per-string, then *how* you do it depends on how you intend to store said classifications. The start for this might be:

```r
str(m2 <- apply(m, 1, function(r) names(which(r))))
# List of 8
#  $ : chr "p1"
#  $ : chr "p1"
#  $ : chr "p2"
#  $ : chr "p2"
#  $ : chr [1:2] "p1" "p2"
#  $ : chr "p3"
#  $ : chr [1:2] "p1" "p3"
#  $ : chr(0)
```

This is one direct storage: each element of the `list` corresponds to `strings`, and it contains zero or more pattern names. If this is for human-eyes consumption, you might want to convert this into a comma-delimited set:

```r
sapply(m2, paste, collapse = ",")
# [1] "p1"    "p1"    "p2"    "p2"    "p1,p2" "p3"    "p1,p3" ""
```

or for more formal database storage, how about

```r
stringids <- seq_len(length(strings)) # perhaps you have something better?
d <- data.frame(
  stringid = rep(stringids, times = lengths(m2)),
  ptnmatch = unlist(m2),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
d
#   stringid ptnmatch
# 1        1       p1
# 2        2       p1
# 3        3       p2
# 4        4       p2
# 5        5       p1
# 6        5       p2
# 7        6       p3
# 8        7       p1
# 9        7       p3
```

Notice how string 8 (that I modified to have no categories) is not included, this is by-design here. Once could always force it back in with:

```r
misses <- setdiff(stringids, unique(d$stringid))
misses
# [1] 8

d <- rbind(d, data.frame(stringid = misses, ptnmatch = rep(NA, length(misses))),
           stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
d
#    stringid ptnmatch
# 1         1       p1
# 2         2       p1
# 3         3       p2
# 4         4       p2
# 5         5       p1
# 6         5       p2
# 7         6       p3
# 8         7       p1
# 9         7       p3
# 10        8     <NA>
```